# Setting CSS Class/Styles using Zend Framework HtmlTag View Helper

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am trying to add CSS Class & inline style to a form element's/decorator. I tried

```
$this->addElement('text', 'honeypot', array(
    ...
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Label',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'honeypot', 'style' => 'display: none'))
    )
));
```

But the `<p>` didn't have the `class` & `style` attributes attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me. Are you resetting the element decorators later on using `Zend_Form::setElementDecorators()` or something similar?

[image]

FYI, you should probably have a semi-colon after your inline style rule, eg

```
'style' => 'display: none;'
```